# Adobe Air .air files: are they 32 bit, 64 bit or neither?

Tags: air

I am curious to know if an Adobe Air, when deployed a .air file is actually 32 bit or 64 bit.

I understand that any native version would be one or the other.

I think its neither because .air is just a package containing an swf?

The Adobe docs do not answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it is not containing runtime, OS will be using either 32bit or 64bit runtime, depending on which is installed on system. Note that it is not applicable to bult apps in `.exe`, `.apk`, `.ipa` or if you use native extensions